# SQL sort a column containing multiple type value

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-server-2012

Suppose a column in a database table contains mixed type values, ex: it contains *numbers*, *strings*, *NULL* or *empty*.

column
97
2
19
NULL
81
TS
45

How do I sort the column in ascending order, like numbers first, then comes the strings lexicographically, then the null and empty value?

Description update:
*(Based on @GolezTrol's comment below)*
The type of the column is 'varchar' (like "1", "10", "4", "D", ""). The default sort procedure (asc) orders them lexiographically ("1", "10", "4", "D"), I would like them to be sorted numerically first, then rest of the values lexiographically.

Comment: *"Suppose a column in a database table contains mixed type values"* There you are going wrong. A column has a specific type. You cannot store a number in one row and a string in the next.

Comment: GolezTrol is right, unless you mean the column is type string but have numbers only and string on it.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GolezTrol The type of the column is 'varchar' (like "1", "10", "4", "D", ""). The default sort orders them lexiographically ("1", "10", "4", "D"), I would like them to be sorted numerically first, then rest of the values lexiographically.

Comment: @GordonLinoff DB engine tag has been added.

Answer (score 2):

If the column type is varchar, then by default the sorting order would be based on first ascii values. If first character is same, then second and so on. So the order for your scenario would be (with ascii values)

1. empty value(32)
2. number(48-57)
3. string(65-122)
4. null (null)

If you are sure that your data will not have special characters, then you can replace null with '{' (125) and empty values with '}' (127) and try sorting then. Query would depend on your database but this could be a start point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the below code is not a solution, but based on the scenario and data selected (maximum length 2) in the db, it worked and solved the case.

```
select TH from LEDGER
where TH<>''
group by th
order by 
case ISNUMERIC(TH)
    when 1 then cast(th as int)
    else ascii(substring(upper(th), 1, 1))-14
end;
```

I would like to find the solution to be more generic and work on any scenario. Any suggestion are welcomed.